# How to convert IF expression in sql to Derived column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

```
If(HampPRAPrinForg = 2, If(PrincipalForgive = 1, true, false), 
    If(HampPRAPrinForg = 1, true, 
       If(HampPRAPrinForg = null_integer, null_boolean, false))
```

Comment: Help my brain, what is the code supposed to do? Yes, I see the tests for `HampPRAPrinForg` and `PrincipalForgive` but what is the task you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: i am pulling data from one table1( server1) to another table2 ( server2). column from table2 is derivd from combination of columns in table1(HampPRAPrinForg,PrincipalForgive)

Answer (score 4):

```
(HampPRAPrinForg == 2) ? (PrincipalForgive == 1 ? true : false) : (HampPRAPrinForg == 1, true, (HampPRAPrinForg == null_integer ? null_boolean : false))
```